# Magento 2 GTM js library sometimes loading sometimes not

Tags: javascript, cookies, magento2, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We are using Magento 2 with a third-party extension for GTM as noticed sometimes GTM https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-xyz is loading and sometimes it is not loading when we are checking in the browser console network tab.

Does anyone face this type of issue?

Comment: Which extension you are using?

Comment: @Cyclonecode Weltpixel for GA4 and Amasty for cookie consent